# How can I make inspect.isar.dev show me the data in my running Flutter build?

Tags: ios, flutter, dart, simulator, flutter-isar

When I run my flutter build in VS code, I see the Isar banner and copy the accompanying link to my Chrome browser, e.g.

```
 ws://127.0.0.1:57558/NBNCkteNWbM=/wsLaunching lib/main.dart on iPad Pro (11-inch) (4th generation) in debug mode...
Xcode build done.                                           32.2s
Connecting to VM Service at ws://127.0.0.1:57558/NBNCkteNWbM=/ws
flutter: ╔════════════════════════════════════════════════════╗
flutter: ║                ISAR CONNECT STARTED                ║
flutter: ╟────────────────────────────────────────────────────╢
flutter: ║        Open the link to connect to the Isar        ║
flutter: ║       Inspector while this build is running.       ║
flutter: ╟────────────────────────────────────────────────────╢
flutter: ║ https://inspect.isar.dev/3.1.0/#/57558/NBNCkteNWbM ║
flutter: ╚════════════════════════════════════════════════════╝
```

But the browser just spins and shows itself 'initializing engine' forever. I just tried setting

```
inspector: true,
```

in the Isar.Open statement but it made no difference.

To be super clear, I am copying

```
https://inspect.isar.dev/3.1.0/#/57558/NBNCkteNWbM
```

into the browser, and getting this and nothing else:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue using Brave (based on Chrome) and resolved it by disabling shields for the `inspect.isar.dev` domain.

Check for ad blockers, popup blockers, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Inspector ran fine on every machine except one. The problem was all the controls I had set up in the HOSTS File. I just erased most of the HOSTS entries and then inspector worked.